# how to convert tensor output in to image and save in tensorflow2?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, tensor

```
    tensor = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(tensor, np.uint8)
    tensor = tf.squeeze(tensor)

    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    plt.axis('off')
    return plt.imsave("hello.jpg",tensor)
```

this is function i am using to convert output tensor of my model in to image and save it

```
p=model_(x)
tensor_to_image(p)
```

and i got the below error after running code

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-181-0c223af55670> in <module>()
----> 1 tensor_to_image(p)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cm.py in to_rgba(self, x, alpha, bytes, norm)
    215                         alpha = np.uint8(alpha * 255)
    216                     m, n = x.shape[:2]
--> 217                     xx = np.empty(shape=(m, n, 4), dtype=x.dtype)
    218                     xx[:, :, :3] = x
    219                     xx[:, :, 3] = alpha

TypeError: data type not understood
```

my model is a neural style transfer model on images

Comment: What is 'x'? Does it have the attribute 'dtype'? Maybe check what type of data it is with `type(x.dtype)`

Comment: x is dtype float32  .actually x is a tensor of an image to be inputed in to model